# How to sum values in F# Map collection

Tags: f#

I have a `Map<string,int>` where I want to sum all values.

It will be used as word dictionary in a toy spelling corrector which is described [here](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Naive attempt

```
let wc myMap =
    Map.toSeq myMap
    |> Seq.sumBy (fun kvp -> (snd kvp))
```

**error FS0071** *Consider adding further type constraints*

Attempt 1

```
type MapFn = Map<string,int> -> int
let wc:MapFn = (function wm ->
                            Map.toSeq wm
                            |> Seq.sumBy (fun kvp -> (snd kvp)))
```

Attempt 2

```
type WordMap = WordMap of Map<string,int>
let wc (WordMap wm) = 
    Map.toSeq wm
    |> Seq.sumBy (fun kvp -> (snd kvp))
```

Both attempts work, however I would like code tidier. Like sample code in Python `sum(WORDS.values())`.

```
WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))

def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())): 
    return WORDS[word] / N
```

Also wonder if type `Map<string,int>` is the best choice for my dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map element is a key/value pair (KeyValuePair<string, int> in your example), not a tuple. So you should use kvp.Value instead of snd kvp, for example:

```
myMap |> Seq.sumBy(fun item -> item.Value )
```

or using Map.fold

```
myMap |> Map.fold (fun state key value -> state + value)  0
```

Comment: Just to add, with the `+` operator and the initial `0` state in his `Map.fold` example, the compiler deduces that the most generic your function will be is of type `Map<'a, int> -> int`. So you're stuck with that at the very least. (The `Seq.sumBy` causes the compiler to complain about type constraints.) I would recommend the one that uses `Map.fold` as well due to clarity.